# Novel about an alternate dimension where human perception is warped

Tags: story-identification, novel, space, parallel-universe

I'm looking for a novel series, probably for teens, published in 80's-90's, which has a spaceship traveling to an alternate dimension.

One distinguishing feature is that human senses stop behaving normally in the alternate dimension, e.g. upon passing through the portal, the spaceship interior doesn't look like the spaceship interior, even if it is still the same spaceship.

I recall that the character was walking in the spaceship while holding onto handle/railing in the ship, and it stopped being metallic cold when the spaceship passed into the other dimension.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year or decade did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall any details about the cover?

Comment: @LogicDictates: It should be published around 80's-90's but unfortunately I don't remember the cover nor the plots. I only recall the warped human sensation part :(